# Syntax error near (%s %s %s) using mysql.connector for Python

Tags: python, sql

I have several queries. Most of my insert queries work and they follow the same format as this one (I even copy pasted and modified as needed). For some reason, this query is throwing me a syntax error and I'm not sure why.

I've looked at the various solutions on SO for resolving this error. Seems like people get it for a variety of different reasons, and I'm not sure exactly what the reason is for this error being thrown at me. I can't see the problem with the statement.

```
def set_prices(game_name, vendor_id, vendor_name, game_id, game_platform, vendor_store_link, current_price_at_vendor, previous_price_at_vendor, historical_low_at_vendor):
    # Create the query
    insert_price_data = """ INSERT INTO game_vendors
            (game_name, vendor_id, vendor_name, game_id, game_platform, vendor_store_link, current_price_at_vendor, previous_price_at_vendor, historical_low_at_vendor, historical_low_date)
            VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s); """

    vals = (game_name, vendor_id, vendor_name, game_id, game_platform, vendor_store_link, current_price_at_vendor, previous_price_at_vendor, historical_low_at_vendor, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d").replace('/', '-'))

    send_to_db(insert_price_data, vals)

set_prices("borderlands 3", "1", "xbox", "26", "xbox one", "xbox.com", "45", "45", "25")
```

I wasn't expected to receive this error, as it had not occurred with any of my previous SQL statements.

> "1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)' at line 4"

I bet it is something minor I'm overlooking.

Update `send_to_db()` function:

```
def send_to_db(query,  multi_result=False, vals=None):
    # this function opens a database query for a connection
    # build engine for database
    db_engine = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="",
        database="mydb",
    )

    # Initiate the cursor
    cursor = db_engine.cursor()
    # row = None
    # rows = None

    try:
        if vals:
            # insert queries require vals
            cursor.execute(query, vals)
            db_engine.commit()

        else:
            # select queries which don't require vals
            cursor.execute(query)
            if multi_result:
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
                return rows
            else:
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                return row

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(error)

    finally:
        if db_engine.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            db_engine.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
            db_engine.disconnect()
```

Comment: What is your `send_to_db` function?

Comment: Updated with the function. As noted, this function works with other statements I have in my program. I suspect it isn't the function, but the statement itself. But hopefully you can spot something I can't. I've been pulling my hair out!

Comment: shouldn't it be called like this: `send_to_db(insert_price_data, vals=vals)`? Otherwise, `vals` gets passed as `multi_result` parameter.

Comment: You might be right actually. I'll test that.

Comment: You're a genius! That solved the issue. Thanks for spotting that. I changed my DB function yesterday and totally forgot that I could have bugged in. Thanks Norok2!